# How do I preserve my mushroom stuffing for freezing?

Tags: stuffing

What do I have to do to preserve a mushroom stuffing with eggs, crab and cheese as ingredients so I can freeze it for use at a later date?

Comment: When you say "mushroom stuffing" do you mean "stuffing that goes inside mushrooms" or "stuffing made out of mushrooms plus other ingredients? If the former, are you trying only to preserve the stuffing itself or the mushrooms with the stuffing in them?

Answer (score 1):

But, as Catija indicates below its not clear whether you are stuffing mushrooms or whether the stuffing contains mushroom. Based on the other stuff used I am going to go ahead and guess that you are stuffing mushrooms with this, but I am going to make this and if/then answer to cover both cases.

If the stuffing contains mushrooms:

you have to decide whether it's ok for the mushroom to get mushy, then you don't have to do anything special, just make sure it's in a freezer bag and get all the air out. However, If you want your mushroom to stay firm, then don't freeze it, and wait until you get closer to the day you need to use it, then you can refrigerate it for a day or two.

If not:

I think you'll be just fine to freeze it. I might freeze the portions on a cookie sheet first before putting into a bag, it will make thawing swifter and more painless.

Comment: It's unclear to me actually, whether there is any mushroom in the stuffing itself...

Comment: @Catija you know what? based on your comment, I re-read it and you are right it's not clear. Is this a stuffing for mushrooms or is this a stuffing that contains mushrooms. It's probably the former in which case I think freezing will be just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Here you still need to consider what kind of freezing you are using. Dry freezing dramatically dehydrates food and shortens the shelf life. Homemade mushroom gravy, once cooked and stored neatly and properly, will remain usable for up to three days in the refrigerator.

Comment: What do you mean by "dry freezing"? It almost sounds like you mixed up the phrase "freeze drying", but I doubt that anybody is doing this at home. Also, freezing extends shelf life, doesn't shorten it.